onclick function not working in Blazor Maui App
I want to update an SQL table by checking/unchecking the checkbox in Blazor Maui Hybrid app. No matter what I try, it won't change anything in the SQL table because the function is not being called.
Here's the code for the checkbox:
<th><input type="checkbox" checked = "@equipment.IsCheckedOut" onclick="CheckOutEquipment(@equipment);"></th>

Here's the function it calls:
public void CheckOutEquipment(Equipment equipment)
{
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = "localhost",
            UserID = "root",
            Password = "password",
            Database = "demo211",
        };
    MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    connection.Open();
    
    string update = $"update Equipment set CheckedOut = 1 where ID={equipment.ID}";
    MySqlCommand updateCmd = new MySqlCommand(update,connection);
    updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
}


What is the problem?  Is the function being called?  Is the SQL connection being opened?   Does the query execute?   Are there any errors or exceptions?

the problem is the function is not being called, and i've tried every iteration with the '@', onclick, and onchange

Your current version attempts to call a JavaScript function while it should be calling a C# function.
To fix this, you need an @ in front of the event name like so:
<th><input type="checkbox" checked = "@equipment.IsCheckedOut" @onclick="() => CheckOutEquipment(equipment)"></th>


unfortunately this doesn't fix it, and there error says 'CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' do 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'

@captflufferbunz Ahh yeah that makes sense. I'll update my answer

First, I would suggest you make sure the check/uncheck event is hitting the function. Since it is C#, add the @ in front of the onclick. The reason is to establish that we can hit the function from the checkbox.
<th><input type="checkbox" checked = "@equipment.IsCheckedOut" @onclick="CheckOutEquipment"></th>


public void CheckOutEquipment(ChangeEventArgs args)
{
 Console.WriteLine(args.Value.ToString());
}

After this works, we need to pass the Equipment token to the CheckOutEquipment function.
<input type="checkbox" checked="@equipment.IsCheckedOut" @onclick="(args) => CheckOutEquipment(args, equipment)" />


public void CheckOutEquipment(ChangeEventArgs args, Equipment equipment)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Equipment ID: {equipment.Id}, Checked Out: {args.Value}");
    }

